# How to execute performance tests with selenium, junit and jenkins

Tags: java, performance, selenium, jenkins, junit

I know JMeter is a good performance tool.

Unfortunately, for performance tests I only have: Selenium, Junit, Jenkins (or additional plugins for Jenkins. Do you know any?)

I have Junit tests written in Selenium.

Each of the nodes in Jenkins is able to serve 5 threads. Is it a good solution to run tests on several machines in parallel (in Chrome) to easily check if each test will pass at a similar time?

Maybe you have another way to test performance using Selenium, Junit and Jenkins (or Jenkins plugins)?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is meant for browser automation and not for analysing the performance. I would not suggest to do so. Since you are about to run tests on several machines in parallel, it would ease your job on executing the scripts faster and giving you results on performance of application.